# How to enable authentication for an ACI webservice in Azure Machine Learning service?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-instances

I am able to deploy a Azure Machine learning prediction service in my workspace `ws` using the syntax

```
aciconfig = AciWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=1, 
                                               memory_gb=8, 
                                               tags={"method" : "some method"}, 
                                               description='Predict something')
```

and then

```
service = Webservice.deploy_from_image(deployment_config = aciconfig,
                                       image = image,
                                       name = service_name,
                                       workspace = ws)
```

as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where#aci).
However, this exposes a service publicly and this is not really optimal.

What's the easiest way to shield the ACI service? I understand that passing an [`auth_enabled=True`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.webservice.aciwebservice?view=azure-ml-py#deploy-configuration-cpu-cores-none--memory-gb-none--tags-none--properties-none--description-none--location-none--auth-enabled-none--ssl-enabled-none--enable-app-insights-none--ssl-cert-pem-file-none--ssl-key-pem-file-none--ssl-cname-none-) parameter may do the job, but then how can I instruct a client (say, using `curl` or Postman) to use the service afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-consume-web-service#call-the-service-c) for an example (in C#). When you enable auth, you will need to send the API key in the "Authorization" header in the HTTP request:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authKey);
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-consume-web-service#authentication-key) how to retrieve the key.

Comment: If we have multiple users and/or applications that will consume the API, we shouldn't expose the same primary API key to them all. How to do this?

Comment: You could for instance put Azure API Management in front. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/

Comment: Yes, I already looked at Azure API Management, but it was unclear where to pass the primary token. Can you elaborate a bit? Appreciate it.

Comment: See here how to add a HTTP header: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetHTTPheader
So you would do user authorization in API management and then have API mgmt inject the same primary key for all requests to you ML backend service

Answer (score 0):

First, retrieve the primary and secondary keys with a (Python) syntax like

```
service.get_keys()
```

If you are using `curl`, the syntax may look like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <authKey>" -X POST -d '{"data": [some data]}' http://<url>:<port>/<method>
```

where `<authKey>` is one of the keys retrieved above.